# How do i save some data from the UIWebView in an application for IPad

Tags: ios, ipad, uiwebview

I am making an app for an IPad.
I have loaded a local html file in the UIWebView. I have now collected some data from the user. I want to save this locally so it can be used by the application for some other purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You could start reading about Property lists. I think that it could be very useful for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

store the information in plist if it is not huge and use it whenever required.